# MUI Select Border not extending to label, white space

Tags: select, material-ui, border

I am trying to render a dropdown using `@mui/material/Select` and want the top border to extend next to the label. Right now there is white space between the label and the right edge of the dropdown div. I checked dev tools and the only border property I could identify was `border-radius`. Is there a way to make the border extend up next to edge of the label ?

[Rendered Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g44A6.png)

**YearDropdown.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { BEM_Date } from 'containerMfe/Functions';

const Form = styled(FormControl)`
  width: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 15px!important;

  & > div > div {
    padding: 10px;
  }
`

export default function YearDropdown({ columns, yr, handler }) {
  const years = [...new Set(columns.map(date => BEM_Date(date).getFullYear()))]
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Form>
        <InputLabel id='year-dropdown-label'>Year</InputLabel>
        <Select
          fullWidth
          labelId='year-dropdown-label'
          id='year-dropdown'
          value={yr}
          onChange={handler}
        >
          {years.map(year => <MenuItem key={'year-' + year} value={year}>{year}</MenuItem>)}
        </Select>

      </Form>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and could not solve it. In my case, not setting a value or default value seemed to fix the label issue, but my input had to be controlled.

What did work was using the `TextField` component, with the `select` prop set to true with `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}`.

Here is my original Select whose label I could *not* fix, followed by an equivalent TextField example that works:

```js
// original select implementation with broken label
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="sort-by-label">Sort By</InputLabel>
  <Select
    label="sort-by-label"
    labelId="sort-by-label"
    id="sort-by"
    value={sortBy}
    onChange={handleSortByChange}
    variant="outlined"
  >
    {keys.map((key) => (
      <MenuItem key={key} value={key}>
        {key}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>

// equivalent TextField implementation that seems to have a functional label
<TextField
  select
  value={sortBy}
  onChange={handleSortByChange}
  variant="outlined"
  label="Sort By"
  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
>
  {keys.map((key) => (
    <MenuItem key={key} value={key}>
      {key}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```